# Forbid Python from writing anything to disk

Tags: python, linux

Are there any command-line options or configurations that forbids Python from writing to disk?

I know I can hack `open` but it doesn't sound very safe.

---

I've hosted some Python tutorials I wrote myself on my website for friends who want to learn Python, and I want them to have access to a Python console so they can try as they learn. This is done by creating a Python subprocess from the http server.

However, I do not want them to accidentally or intentionally damage my server, so I need to forbid the Python process from writing anything to disk.

Also I'm running the server on Ubuntu Linux so doing it Python-wise or system-wise are both OK.

Comment: If they have full access to your system (even as a normal user) without some kind of jailed runtime they can do a lot more damage than writing to disk, such as launching a reverse shell (through a `subprocess`) and now they effectively have a login/shell to your system through your http process.

Comment: You are trying to build something that been built before, many times. Just forget about re-inventing the wheel; instead, look into existing solutions.

Comment: @GhostCat for example?

Comment: @metatoaster They don't. They can only interact with the http server, and it belongs to a normal user

Comment: @MichaelKim I thought you were going to let your users run unrestricted Python code on your server through that Python subprocess - that Python subprocess can potentially spawn any process (including `bash`) and now they have a shell as the user running httpd.  Honestly, just look at existing solutions.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt there's a way to do this in the interpreter itself: there are way too many things to patch (`open`, `subprocess`, `os.system`, `file`, and probably others). I'd suggest looking into a way of containerizing the python runtime via something like Docker. The containerization gives some guarantees restricting access, though not as much as virtualization. See [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/107850/docker-as-a-sandbox-for-untrusted-code) for more discussion about the security implications.

Running a jupyter/ipython notebook in the docker container would probably be the easiest way to expose a web-frontend. `jupyter` provides a collection of docker containers for this purpose: see https://github.com/jupyter/tmpnb and https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'll check things out